# What am I doing wrong? Omniscape doesnt load my data

Tags: julia, load

I am trying to load the raster data in Omniscape: This is  the task from die website: "Now, load the array using Omniscape's internal read_raster() function or a function from a GIS Julia package of your choice. read_raster() returns a tuple with the data array, a wkt string containing geographic projection info, and an array containing geotransform values. We'll use the wkt and geotransform later."

`julia>  raster_file_path = "C:/Users/keinp/nlcd_2016_frederick_md.tif" "C:/Users/keinp/nlcd_2016_frederick_md.tif"`

`julia> land_cover, wkt, transform = Omniscape.read_raster("nlcd_2016_frederick_md.tif", Float64)`

```
ERROR: UndefVarError: `read_raster` not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] getproperty(x::Module, f::Symbol)
   @ Base .\Base.jl:31
 [2] top-level scope
   @ REPL[16]:1
```

This example can be found on the following page: https://docs.circuitscape.org/Omniscape.jl/latest/examples/
I already installed Omniscape, and also typed in: using Omniscape.

i tried to use the path relative and absolute.

I also tried to load the file with ArchGDAL, which does not work either.

What am I doing wrong? Can anybody help me?

Comment: Can you show the output of running `import Pkg; Pkg.status()`?